# popUp appears before clicking the button

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup, alert

The popUp alert should only appear when I click the "button" (the only word on the screen is the button) but instead the popUp alert shows before even clicking!

```js
var saldo=100;   

var popUp= document.getElementById("buy");
function doPopUp(custo2){
     
              if (custo2>saldo){
                alert("You don't have enough money!");
              }
          }
             
              
popUp.onclick=doPopUp(200);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>buyyy</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="buy">Buy</a>
<script src="poop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popUp.onclick` expects that you pass a function itself to it. `doPopUp(200)` executes this function and returns it's result - in the end you pass nothing to the onclick event. You can pass a function like this:

```
popUp.onclick=function() { doPopUp(200); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the addeventlistener() function instead of .onclick or use &lgta id="buy" onclick="doPopUp(200);"&rgtBuy&lgt/a&rgt